# XmlReader.Skip - need to read end element on a skip?

Tags: c#, xml

If I skip, do I still need to read the end element?

```
            reader.ReadStartElement("ENCODING");
            reader.Skip();
            reader.ReadEndElement();
```

And I don't get when we need to ReadEndElement.  For example we've gotten by in some of our classes with not using it at all. For example:

```
        using (reader)
        {
            reader.Read();
            reader.ReadStartElement("Envelope");
            reader.ReadStartElement("Body");
            reader.ReadStartElement("RESULT");
            reader.ReadStartElement("SUCCESS");
             _success = reader.ReadString();
            if (!Success)
            {
                if (SomeUtil.ReadUntilElement(reader, "FaultString"))
                {
                    string _errorMessage = reader.ReadString();
                    InvalidOperationException ex = new InvalidOperationException(_errorMessage);

                    throw ex;
                }
                else
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid Error Message");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to match the number of times you call ReadStartElement with the same number of calls to ReadEndElement. It might actually work in some cases when you are at the last elements but in general it is not recommended.

Comment: My boss said we don't need them at all!  and it works!  I started out matching them and then he said we don't need all of them. wtf.  So that's why I was asking because I can't see why it would work without them but it does.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the current element by doing roughly the following:

```
        int depth = reader.Depth;
        while (!reader.EOF && (reader.Depth > depth || reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement))
            reader.Read();
```

By capturing and comparing the depth of the reader we can be sure we found the matching close of the current element.

Comment: This is a good idea. However I'm not sure that the code is quite right because if the EndElement of the element you are trying to skip over is followed by more end elements, then this skips over all of those too.

So for symmetry, what I did was before I started to parse a possible problematic subtree, I recorded the initial depth. Then I parsed away in a try catch. If an exception occurred, I did

while (!reader.EOF && reader.Depth > currentNodeDepth)
{
      reader.Read();
}

Comment: which takes you all the way to the end element without reading it. Then just as a sanity check, I check reader.Name is the element I'm expecting, before calling reader.ReadEndElement.